# library not found for -lSystem - M1 MacBook - Radmc3d

Tags: xcode, gcc, fortran, gfortran, apple-silicon

I am trying to install Radmc3d for the new M1 Mac Book Pro, when running the initial `make` I get the following

```
gfortran -O2 -fopenmp main.o rtglobal_module.o montecarlo_module.o dust_module.o quantum_module.o mathroutines_module.o ioput_module.o stars_module.o amr_module.o amrray_module.o constants_module.o camera_module.o lines_module.o namelist_module.o userdef_module.o gascontinuum_module.o polarization_module.o sources_module.o -o radmc3d
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [radmc3d] Error 1
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this, I have installed ggc through homebrew and have just recently updated Xcode.

Running Big Sur 11.1.